# Proper term for non-linear proportionality

Tags: terminology, relations

I want to express the simple idea that two functions *f* and *g* are related in the following way:

$$
f(x) > f(y) \implies g(x) > g(y)
$$

Or the inverse relation:

$$
f(x) > f(y) \implies g(x) < g(y)
$$

I was going to use the term "proportional" or "inversely proportional", but I understand that in mathematics that implies a linear (or inverse linear) relationship, which is not my case. Is there a better term to express this than something like "$f(x)$ increases as $g(x)$ increases/decreases"?

Comment: I don't know a standard term, but if I were to make one up, I'd choose something like "$f$ and $g$ increase (in)coherently".

Comment: Isn't this the problem that big and little "oh" notation are meant to address?

Comment: @XanderHenderson Mmm, well I was thinking more of a term, but in any case, I don't really want to say either $f \in \mathcal{O}(g)$ or $g \in \mathcal{O}(f)$, since none of them actually "bounds" the other... also I couldn't express the inverse relationship like that, I think.

Comment: If we're making up terms, "$f$ and $g$ are co-ordered".

Comment: This has nothing to do with proportionality, nor with order of magnitudes, just with **order**. This question is a linguistic and semantic challenge indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick with your ideas.
f increases as g increases.
f increases as g decreases.

Comment: Some of the suggestions in the comments are reasonable, but I think that, unless I need to express this relationship many times (in which case I'd probably explicitly make up a term and give a definition), I should avoid using a term that is not really widespread.